# R qqplot aes_ in a function and a function of the data column

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have a data.frame with many columns of the form containing the aggregated values for each time point of variables x,y,z,w ...an:
Time x_mean x_sd y_mean y_sd z_mean y_sd w_mean w_sd ...

Now I want to write a function that plots the mean and a confidence band of +/-1SD around it, with ggplot2. Currently my code looks like:

```
plotfunc <- function(ds1,val) {
  val_mean <- paste(val,"_mean",sep="")
  val_p_sd <- paste(val,"_mean + ",val,"_sd",sep="")
  val_m_sd <- paste(val,"_mean - ",val,"_sd",sep="")
  ggplot() + geom_line(data=ds1,aes_q(x=as.name("TIME"),y=as.name(val_mean),color="good")) +
geom_ribbon(data=ds1,aes_q(x=as.name("TIME"),ymin=as.name(val_m_sd),ymax=as.name(val_p_sd),alpha=0.3,fill="good")) 
}
```

And I call it with:

```
plotfunc(df,"x")
```

It complains:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x_mean - x_sd' not found
```

How do I get the upper and lower bounds? Do I need to use `substitute` or `quote` ?

Comment: Did you try `aes_string` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `aes_string` and corrected some syntax errors in your function code:
- color "good" unkown
- the color argument, which is specified to a fixed value, has hence to be outside the `aes` function

```
df = data.frame("TIME"=11:20, "x_mean"=rnorm(10, mean=10), "x_sd"=rnorm(10, mean=1, sd=0.1),
                "y_mean"=rnorm(10, mean=12), "y_sd"=rnorm(10, mean=2, sd=0.2))

plotfunc <- function(ds1,val) {
  val_mean <- paste(val,"_mean",sep="")
  val_p_sd <- paste(val,"_mean + ",val,"_sd",sep="")
  val_m_sd <- paste(val,"_mean - ",val,"_sd",sep="")
  ggplot() + geom_line(data=ds1,aes_string(x=as.name("TIME"),y=as.name(val_mean)),color="red") +
    geom_ribbon(data=ds1,aes_string(x=as.name("TIME"),ymin=as.name(val_m_sd),ymax=as.name(val_p_sd)),alpha=0.3,fill="blue") 
} 

plotfunc(df,"x")
```

[image]
Is that OK for you?

Comment: though one could probably make your function much simpler.